# Good practices for refactoring initialization of a lot of variables in one method

Tags: java

I am writing a rest controller along with crud service, which will use legacy code, which is still used in different places in application. Its purpose is to export an Excel file.
I am refactoring a bit, in order to have cleaner code (as clean as it is possible in this situation, I don't want to re-write the whole app) and for easier unit testing.

So, let's say, I have a method which calls a lot of services with parameters based on filter (input) and then uses it to generate excel file. What would be a good practice to clean it?

I would appreciate some tips and tricks, as well as, good discussion ;)

```
    @Override
    public Downloadable<Workbook> getExcel(ExcelFilterTO filter) {

    List<String> someList= someService.getString(filter.getParam1(), filter.getParam2()).stream().collect(toList());

    List<Integer> someList2 = someService.getInt(filter.getParam1(), filter.getParam2(), filter.getParam3(), filter.getParam4());

       TranslationSet translationsSet = translationService.getTranslationsSet(filter.getParam4(),
            TranslationsGroup.SOME_TYPE);

       SomeClass classObject = someService.doSomething(filter.getParam1());

    ...
    ...
    String fileSuffix = ExcelUtils.EXCEL_EXPORT_FILE_NAME_SUFFIX;

    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle  .getBundle(BundleNames.getBundle(filter.getParam2()).getName());


    Workbook workbook = excelExport.exportExcel(someList, someList2 , fileSuffix, translationsSet, filter.getParam3());

    String fileName = excelExport.getExcelFileName(resourceBundle, someList3, filter.param6(), classObject);

    return new DownloadableResource<>(fileName, XLS.getContentType(), workbook);
    }`
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could wrap all of `List<Sting>` objects into a single line with commas and the initialize them on the preceding lines. For example `List<String> obj1, obj2, obj3, ...;`

Answer (score -1):

You can shorten your initialization by adding utility methods, but I guess it's a matter of taste.

```
// utility method
List<Integer> intList(Supplier<String> param1, Supplier<String> param2) {
    return someService.getString(param1.apply(filter), param2.apply(filter)).stream().collect(toList());
}
```

and

```
// utility method
List<String> stringList(Supplier<String> param1, Supplier<String> param2) {
    return someService.getString(filter.getParam1(), filter.getParam2()).stream().collect(toList());
}
```

so you can have

```
List<Integer> someList2 = intList(filter::getParam1, filter::getParam2);
List<Integer> someList4 = intList(filter::getParam4, filter::getParam3);
```

and

```
List<String> someList = stringList(filter::getParam1, filter::getParam2);
List<String> someList3 = stringList(filter::getparam6, filter::getParam5);
```

in your constructor.